# Applying a function to all combinations of elements

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function of three variables such as

```
f <- function(x,y,z) x*y*z
```

Now, given three data sets

```
X <- seq(1,10)
Y <- seq(11,20)
Z <- seq(21,30)
```

I want to efficiently evaluate `f` on all combinations of elements from `X,Y,Z`. What is the smartest way to do this? (In practice, my function is more complicated and the sets are very large).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this. Using `prod` to get the product of the elements by lines from `expand.grid`.

```
X <- 1:3
Y <- 4:6
Z <- 7:9

apply(expand.grid(X, Y, Z), 1, function(x) prod(x))
 [1]  28  56  84  35  70 105  42  84 126  32  64  96  40  80 120  48  96 144  36
[20]  72 108  45  90 135  54 108 162
```

Using an arbitrary function

```
f <- function(x, y, z) x * y * z
```

```
apply(expand.grid(X, Y, Z), 1, function(x) f(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
 [1]  28  56  84  35  70 105  42  84 126  32  64  96  40  80 120  48  96 144  36
[20]  72 108  45  90 135  54 108 162
```

With `dplyr`, using `crossing`

Note the difference between `crossing` and `expand_grid`/`expand.grid`

> ‘crossing()’ is a wrapper around ‘expand_grid()’ that
> de-duplicates and sorts its inputs

So its naturally a bit slower, gaining a functionality often needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

crossing(X, Y, Z) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(result = f(X, Y, Z))
# A tibble: 27 × 4
# Rowwise: 
       X     Y     Z result
   <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1     1     4     7     28
 2     1     4     8     32
 3     1     4     9     36
 4     1     5     7     35
 5     1     5     8     40
 6     1     5     9     45
 7     1     6     7     42
 8     1     6     8     48
 9     1     6     9     54
10     2     4     7     56
# … with 17 more rows
```

And finally a `data.table` approach using `CJ`

> ‘CJ’ : * C *ross * J *oin. A ‘data.table’ is formed from the
> cross product of the vectors.

```
library(data.table)

CJ(X, Y, Z)[, f(X, Y, Z)]
 [1]  28  32  36  35  40  45  42  48  54  56  64  72  70  80  90  84  96 108  84
[20]  96 108 105 120 135 126 144 162
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer probably depends on the size of `X`, `Y` and `Z`.  There are a few options for expanding all combinations of values, `expand.grid()` from base R and `expand_grid()` from the `tidyr` package as well as `CJ()` from the `data.table` package as @Andre Wildberg mentioned.  You could then compute the results of the function with either a for loop over the rows of the expanded dataset, `apply()`, with `mutate()` in a pipeline or with a `data.table` approach.  Depending on the size these solutions have different properties.   First, consider the situation posed above where each is of length 10.  Looking at the benchmarks for `expand.grid()` vs `expand_grid()` vs `CJ()`, they are of similar magnitude, though the `expand.grid()` and `CJ()` approaches are faster, on average, than the `expand_grid()` approach.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
  

f <- function(x,y,z) x*y*z

X <- seq(1,10)
Y <- seq(11,20)
Z <- seq(21,30)

microbenchmark(
  expand_grid(X,Y,Z), 
  expand.grid(X,Y,Z), 
  CJ(X, Y, Z), times=25)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                  expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
#>  expand_grid(X, Y, Z) 245.750 259.667 361.7473 269.126 282.834 2507.043    25
#>  expand.grid(X, Y, Z) 102.750 107.084 147.9838 112.584 122.625  952.251    25
#>           CJ(X, Y, Z) 115.293 124.168 202.5123 132.209 137.251 1885.709    25
#>  cld
#>    a
#>    a
#>    a
```

When considering the different ways of computing the result I've implemented four solutions:

- `exp1()` is the for loop with `expand.grid()`
- `exp2()` is the `apply()` with `expand.grid()`.
- `exp3()` is the `dplyr` solution with `expand_grid()`
- `exp4()` is the `data.table` solution with `CJ()`.

The `data.table` solution is the clear winner here beating the `dplyr` solution by a factor of about 3 (though not a statistically significant difference according to the CLD).

```r
exp1 <- function(){
df = expand.grid(X, Y, Z)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$prod = f(df[i,1], df[i,2], df[i,3])
}
}

exp2 <- function(){
  df = expand.grid(X, Y, Z)
  df$prod <- apply(df, 1, function(x)f(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
}

exp3 <- function(){
  df = expand_grid(X,Y,Z)
  df %>% mutate(prod = f(X,Y,Z))
}

exp4 <- function(){
  CJ(X,Y,Z)[,prod := f(X,Y,Z)]
}

microbenchmark(exp1(), exp2(), exp3(), exp4(), times = 25)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#>  exp1() 28588.667 29375.543 31602.4207 30595.001 32012.667 44312.917    25   c
#>  exp2()  3129.459  3254.584  3498.8607  3285.625  3341.584  6549.251    25  b 
#>  exp3()  1334.209  1411.834  2072.8457  1691.376  1825.626  9790.917    25 ab 
#>  exp4()   357.501   403.084   829.6241   481.459   559.668  7319.542    25 a
```

If we increase the length of the variables to 30 from 10, we can see that things change a bit. `CJ()` is about twice as fast as `expand_grid()` which is in turn about twice as fast as `expand.grid()`.

```r
X <- seq(1,30)
Y <- seq(11,40)
Z <- seq(21,50)


microbenchmark(
  expand_grid(X,Y,Z), 
  expand.grid(X,Y,Z),
  CJ(X,Y,Z), times=25)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                  expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
#>  expand_grid(X, Y, Z) 298.834 321.542 485.6574 429.084 453.626 2516.376    25
#>  expand.grid(X, Y, Z) 610.584 729.084 750.1874 785.167 796.834  813.584    25
#>           CJ(X, Y, Z) 132.542 162.750 190.0006 201.292 214.126  260.959    25
#>  cld
#>   b 
#>    c
#>  a
```

When looking at the different ways of computing the function, the results are equally clear. The `data.table` solution is faster than the `dplyr` solution by a factor of about 3, though again not statistically significantly different. Both the `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions are significantly quicker than either solution that uses `expand.grid().

```r
microbenchmark(exp1(), exp2(), exp3(), exp4(), times = 25)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr         min          lq         mean      median          uq
#>  exp1() 1603137.001 1652454.959 1702111.1240 1666486.751 1699009.251
#>  exp2()   85320.126   89976.043   92332.3890   92130.709   94564.959
#>  exp3()    1604.750    1708.334    2302.5940    2199.292    2334.959
#>  exp4()     505.417     541.418     699.1174     723.834     793.001
#>          max neval cld
#>  2110589.459    25   c
#>   101803.250    25  b 
#>     4462.126    25 a  
#>      971.501    25 a
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: After I posted this, one of the answers uses `crossing()` from `tidyr`.  In both the length-10 and length-30 examples, `crossing()` is slower than `expand_grid()` by a factor of around 1.5-2.

Answer (score 1):

Create combinations using `expand.grid` and iterate over the resulting data frame:

```
f <- function(x,y,z) x*y*z

X <- seq(1,10)
Y <- seq(11,20)
Z <- seq(21,30)

df = expand.grid(X, Y, Z)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    print(f(df[i, 1], df[i, 2], df[i, 3]))
}
```